# Is the GitHub token saved to my environment variables in Travis CI publicly accessible?

Tags: github, encryption, continuous-integration, token, travis-ci

To encrypt GitHub tokens to use them in your `.travis.yml` you seem to need the Travis CI CLI tool - which I can't install right now.

Therefore I didn't put the GitHub token in my `.travis.yml` but rather created a new environment variable `GITHUB_TOKEN` in the repository settings at https://travis-ci.org and use it like this:

```
github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
```

Now I can use the token to deploy to GitHub releases, for example.

Is this safe? Or are my environment variables in Travis CI somehow publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by now: No, in general, they're not public. Yes, if you follow some rules, it seems perfectly safe to use them for sensitive information. To quote directly from the docs at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings about environment variables:

> Define variables in the Repository Settings that (...) contain sensitive data, such as third-party credentials.

Some reasonable rules to keep in mind:

1. Most importantly: Hide them from the logs with the ON/OFF switch in the settings.

   > By default, the value of these new environment variables is hidden from the `export` line in the logs. This corresponds to the behavior of encrypted variables in your `.travis.yml`. The variables are stored encrypted in our systems, and get decrypted when the build script is generated.
2. Define them correctly with `"` if necessary.

   > These values are used directly in your build, so make sure to escape special characters (for bash) accordingly. In particular, if a value contains spaces, you should put quotes around that value. E.g. `my secret passphrase` should be written `"my secret passphrase"`.

Also important to know: even if your environment variables are hidden in the logs, someone could still submit a pull request to your repository with malicious code and access the variable this way. Therefore, the variables are not available within builds from pull requests:

> Similarly, we do not provide these values to untrusted builds, triggered by pull requests from another repository.